# Why do we have to backpropagate error before applying gradient descent?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation

When I looked at these notes: 
[image]

I was confused about the 4th step. Why should we calculate the errors separately when the gradient descent already computes it. So, would not we be computing the backpropagation error twice?

Thanks

Comment: I really wonder the reason of these downvotes

Comment: I'm not a downvoter, but this looks like http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/ Backprop *is* the process of gradient computation.

Comment: Backpropagation is a nice way to compute the gradients, gradient descent uses these gradients for the optimization process. Your downvotes probably come from this misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

The error isn't computed twice. For example, in my implementation, during step 4, I store the error corresponding to a neuron in a variable associated to this neuron. And during step 5, I use this variable to compute the gradients and update the weights.

My implementation needs to review the neurons two times, for steps 4 and 5. But it seems to be possible to review them only one time, backpropagating the error of a neuron and computing the gradients in the same loop iteration. And being careful to backpropagate the error before updating the weights, because the old weights are used to compute the error of the neurons in the previous layer.